# SQL Server Snapshot replication - Failing to start the Publisher snapshot agent

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to set up a Snapshot replication using an Azure SQL Managed Instance. While trying to see the Snapshot Agent status, I see this error. **"Access to the path '\unc\XXXXXXXX-MANAGEDINSTAxxxxxxx_XXXXXXX_PUBLICATION\20200708132018' is denied."**

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-5-when-you-mount-an-azure-file-share) and made sure that I I set the  Secure transfer required as Disabled, and Allow access from all networks is enabled, and Azure Active Directory Domain Services is disabled in the storage account settngs in the Azure Portal. Still the error remains the same.

Can anybody guide me to find out the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried with two backslashes for the machine name? i.e. `\\unc\...`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did not specify this path, what I provided in the settings was the snapshot folder path like this \\replstorage.file.core.windows.net\replshare, it was wrong before, then I got the error Failed to connect to Azure Storage '' with OS error: 53., after fixing the snapshot folder path, I got the error which is in the question.